# How to avoid kotlin factory class method by subtype?

Tags: java, kotlin, kotlin-reified-type-parameters

i have a question about kotlin:

Imagine you have this:

```
sealed class Graph : Serializable
data class Graph1() : Graph() {}
data class Graph2() : Graph() {}
```

And you want to have a factory class that given a subtype of Graph gives you a GraphView.

So, you have something similar to

```
interface GraphViewFactory{
  fun get(data: Graph1):GraphView
  fun get(data: Graph2):GraphView
}
```

And also you have the implementation for that.

Is possible in kotlin avoid this method explosion of interface having one per graphtype using inline and reified? I'm trying to but i'm not being able.

On the one hand, kotlin interface (I think) does not allow inline functions, on the other hand even without the interface i'm not able to auto cast parameter T as reified to one of the specific subtype class inside the factory class.

Comment: Your story is incomplete. What are the return types of `get` methods? Are they all the same, just `GraphView`? If yes, then you don't really have a problem. If no, and you have `GraphView1` and `GraphView2`, then you have a relationship between input and output types that is not expressible in the static type system.

Comment: Sorry, i've updated the example. Yes, both methods will return GraphView.

Comment: What do you mean when says you don't have a problem? I think you will just cast the type inside the factory based on when(param) is type WhatEver and then cast, but i'm trying to find a way to avoid that casting with reified and inline. (Just curiosity)

Comment: So, what's the issue with this? Can't you pass a `Graph` to `GraphView` and let it decide what to do, using `is` and `as`, possibly? I still don't see the real tension in your question, what exactly is bugging you. Eventually inside `GraphView` you'll have to know which type it is? Or not? Too many open questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wouldn't have to keep creating methods (though you may want to depending on how complex it is to create a `GraphView`), but the number of cases in your `when` will grow.

```
class GraphViewFactory {
  fun get(data: Graph): GraphView {
     return when {
         is Graph1 -> TODO()
         is Graph2 -> TODO()
         else -> IllegalArgumentException()
     }
  }
}
```

Using reified types doesn't buy you anything here.